# Should I state membership in a professional society in authors' list?

Tags: authorship, affiliation, professional-association

I am one of the five authors in a paper about to be submitted. 
Some of us stated in the affiliation their membership in a certain chemical society closely related to both the subject of the paper and the target journal itself (electrochemistry). I am member of a different chemical society not really germane to that field.

Should I state my membership in such society ?

Comment: If other people stated, then it is probably in the rules for authors (I never state such things as I do not understand why)

Comment: @phys_chem_prof: Did you ever clear the case with citing ambiguous "other people"?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on the journal. E.g. In ieee journals it is common practice to add 'member of ieee ...' to the affiliation.

If the journal is the main publication of a society, you should not mention affiliation to a different organization, at least as long as there are no official relations between the both.

If in doubt, send a short question to the editor.

Answer (score 0):

The affiliation does not possess an important role within the case. There are a plethora of the papers, do which composed by the authors, affiliated with different universities, institutes, companies and so on. The important point is that either of them might be irrelevant parties in comparison with the subject, as first glance, but one could assert that the existence of the researchers from different disciplines, employed in various organizations, to cover the R&D-based affairs, leads to the usual emergence of the distinctive and even divergent affiliations.

All in all, you better to stick to your own current affiliation, safely.